# How to select the same list but with an additional variable set?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<MyObject>`

`MyObject` is as follows.

```
public class MyObject
{
   public bool available;
   public bool online;
}
```

Now when I retrieve this `List<MyObject>` from another function, only the `available` field is set. Now I want to set the `online` field of each `MyObject`.

What I currently do is

```
List<MyObject> objectList = getMyObjectList();
objectList.ForEach(x => x.online = IsOnline(x));
```

Now that the `online` property is set, I want to filter again using `Where` to select `MyObject` that is both available and online.

```
objectList.Where(x => x.available && x.online);
```

While I understand that the code above is working and readable, I am curious to know whether there is a **LINQ** way of selecting the same object but with a variable initialized so I can combine all the three lines to one line. Unfortunately `ForEach` does not return the list back.

Something like

```
getMyObjectList().BetterForEach(x => x.online = IsOnline(x)).Where(x => x.available && x.online);
```

`BetterForEach` will return `x` with the previous values set and with the `online` field set as well.

Is there any way function/way to achieve this using LINQ?

**UPDATE**
I've removed other fields of MyObject. MyObject does not only contain these fields but many more. I'd rather not create new instances of MyObject.

Comment: `public MyObject` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is for querying data, not for updating it. So any option you have will not be too pretty, but there are still some options.

You could do this:

```
var result = 
    objectList.Select(x => 
    {
        x.online = IsOnline(x);
        return x;
    });
```

However, that is pretty bad practice. This would be better:

```
var result = 
    objectList.Select(x => new MyObject
    {
        available = x.available,
        online = IsOnline(x)
    });
```

But this creates a collection of new objects, not related to your original set.

---

This kind of code generally indicates there might be something wrong with your basic design. Personally, I'd go with something like this (if you can set up a static method to do the work of `IsOnline`):

```
public class MyObject
{
   public bool Available;
   public bool Online { get { return MyObjectHelper.IsOnline(this); } }
}

...
var result = objectList.Where(x => x.Available && x.Online);
```

Or if you can't set up a static method, maybe this field doesn't need to be in `MyObject` class at all?

```
public class MyObject
{
   public bool Available;
}
...
var result = objectList.Where(x => x.Available && IsOnline(x));
```

Comment: This does not do the filtering part, does it ?

Comment: @C4stor No, it doesn't. I focused just on how to update the source list.

Comment: @C4stor: It's not the filtering part that I am interested in, so he has obviously not focused on that.

Comment: I agree the first approach is bad practice, but +1 because it works. ;)

Comment: Your last two pieces of code made me rethink the design. Thanks! I went ahead with last approach. The reason behind this question was that the availability status was from the database, however the online status had to be queried through a XMPP Connection object I had.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably to make an extension method that is like `ForEach` but returns the list for chaining:

```
public static List<T> ForEachThen<T>(this List<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    source.ForEach(action);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile (simple error, `Action` should be `action`), plus OP specifically asked how do to this other than using a `ForEach` and I don't think wrapping it up in a different method accomplishes that.

Comment: OP specifically asked for a method `so I can combine all the three lines to one line`. This will allow that, while still making it obvious that this is a non-LINQ `ForEach`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var selected = getMyObjectList()
    .Select(x => new MyObject{available=x.available, online = IsOnline(x))
    .Where(x => x.available && x.online);
```

assuming you need to access online in the resulting list..

You could also add a method to MyObject like:

```
public MyObject SetOnline(bool isOnline) {
   this.online = isOnline;
   return this;
}
```

and then do:

```
var selected = getMyObjectList()
    .Select(x => x.SetOnline( IsOnline(x) ))
    .Where(x => x.available && x.online);
```